# Are DOM nodes synchronous?

Tags: html, css, dom, styling

I was wondering whether DOM node attributes are synchronous in terms of styling information? I was reading the following [article](http://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm#The_browsers_we_will_talk_about), and I read the following line

> Scripts asking for style information, like "offsetHeight" can trigger incremental layout synchronously.

From the article, it seems to indicate that there is a "dirty node" system that will pause script execution until the document has been fully laid out. So, if I had a dirty node n, if n.offsetHeight is called from javascript, the article suggest that n.offsetHeight will not return until the offset height has been fully reified. Is my understanding of this correct? Can I rely on the browser to always give me the current stable version of any attached DOM element.

Put succinctly, if I modify some styling on a node (using the style attribute, class names, dynamic css, whatever else), and then read some property that depends on said styling, can I always be certain that the value I get back will be the value of the node with my previous styling applied? If this is not the case, how can I know when my styling changes have been applied?

Comment: Why would you try to access offsetHeight before the DOM is ready anyway? What are you trying to accomplish by this?

Comment: A example might be set a style, read a value derived from that style, do something else immediately based on the value. If the browser guarantees that the value is "current", then that is fine, otherwise I have to somehow ensure that I know the value I am reading has had my style applied.

Comment: Javascript is single threaded, no-one can change it as long as your code is running as long as you're staying sync (no IO/ajax/dom events during that part of your code)

Comment: That may be so, but the flow and paint events occur asynchronously. I cannot guarantee they have occurred, therefore I was curious if I needed to worry about whether they have occurred or whether that concern was "magicked" away for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you read information from the DOM elements, you will always get the current value, and properties that rely on other properties or other elements will always be correctly calculated when you read them.

When you change the DOM so that the layout changes, all the elements are not recalculated directly when you make the change. That would just be a waste, if you change something more that would need another recalculation. The layout remains uncalculated as long as there is no need for the recalculation. If you read a property that is depending on that recalculation, it will be done before the value is returned.

So, by planning how you set and read properties, you can avoid unnessecary recalculations.

Comment: That is what I was hoping was the case. You wouldn't happen to have a reference that specifically states/explains this would you?

Comment: No, it's just the only way that makes any sense. If it was possible to get a value that was not up to date, there would be thousands of questions here about it, and it would be mentioned in the documentation for every single property and method in the DOM.